# pgDump for only the latest tables

Tags: postgresql, psql, pg-dump

I have a service that creates a new table in a DB when a REST API is invoked. I am trying to continuously replicate this DB. I was thinking of using pgDump on a loop in order to get the new table schema, and pgLogical for on-going replication of the new table.
Is there an option in pgDump that allows me to list only the latest table created?

Comment: No there is not. Why not just get/output the schema from whatever process is creating it?

Comment: There is no such option. Your code that creates the table will need to store the creation time somewhere else.